# Group by column, categorize and count string occurrences

Tags: r, grouping, frequency

I have a Problem, which I couldn't solve on my own; my table looks something like that:

```
Type    Model
-----------------
Car     Mercedes
Car     BMW
Plane   Airbus
Car     BMW
Car     Audi
Plane   Boeing
Plane   Airbus
Car     Mercedes
Car     BMW
```

What I want to do, is group my Models by Type and also aggregate and count their frequency, it would look something like that:

```
Car       6
Mercedes  2
BMW       3
Audi      1

Plane     3
Airbus    2
Boeing    1
```

Would be really nice, if you could help me. Until now I just found a solution for counting the frequencies in general, but not for categorizing my values at the same time as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`table` should do pretty much what you want.

```
table(rev(x))
#           Type
# Model      Car Plane
#   Airbus     0     2
#   Audi       1     0
#   BMW        3     0
#   Boeing     0     1
#   Mercedes   2     0
```

You might also be interested in `addmargins`:

```
addmargins(table(rev(x)))
#           Type
# Model      Car Plane Sum
#   Airbus     0     2   2
#   Audi       1     0   1
#   BMW        3     0   3
#   Boeing     0     1   1
#   Mercedes   2     0   2
#   Sum        6     3   9
```

`addmargins(table(rev(x)), 1)` would give you just the column sums instead of both columns and rows.

---

If that's not to your liking, you might try including a `split` or `by` or `tapply` approach:

```
with(x, by(Model, Type, function(x) data.frame(addmargins(table(droplevels(x))))))
# Type: Car
#       Var1 Freq
# 1     Audi    1
# 2      BMW    3
# 3 Mercedes    2
# 4      Sum    6
# -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
# Type: Plane
#     Var1 Freq
# 1 Airbus    2
# 2 Boeing    1
# 3    Sum    3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I tried that solution, but I still need to assign the Models to the Type. So I need something like a header row, which contains the category and its count, and after that row, following the rows with the particular model. It is still important to see which model belongs to which type. @docendodiscimus : same problem with your answer

Comment: Thanks for your help! The second answer was, what I was looking for